# Assigning string in table

Tags: java, swing

Can anyone please help me on this problem. I Have this array of `String` which i want to plot in a table without using jtable:

```
String inventory[][] = {{"Chairs","Tables"},{"Bed","Sofas"}}
```

I use nested `for` loops and `drawLine` to generate this grid but I couldn't manage to put the `String` inside the table. Can anyone help me?

its not my program but this is the closes example that i've got form internet. my program is a bit simillar this.

```
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;
import javax.swing.* ;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class testtable extends JFrame {

   private static final int DRAWING_SIZE = 600;
   private static final int SUBDIVISIONS = 2;
   private static final int SUBDIVISION_SIZE = DRAWING_SIZE / SUBDIVISIONS;

   public testtable() {
      setSize(800, 800);
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      JLabel drawingBoard = new JLabel("Drawing Board");
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
      drawingBoard.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 28));
      add(drawingBoard, gbc);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
         @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setPaint(Color.GRAY);
            for (int i = 1; i < SUBDIVISIONS; i++) {
               int x = i * SUBDIVISION_SIZE;
               g2.drawLine(x, 0, x, getSize().height);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < SUBDIVISIONS; i++) {
               int y = i * SUBDIVISION_SIZE;
               g2.drawLine(0, y, getSize().width, y);
            }
         }
      };
      panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DRAWING_SIZE, DRAWING_SIZE));
      panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
      gbc.gridy++;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      add(panel, gbc);
      JButton saveDrawing = new JButton("SAVE DRAWING");
      gbc.gridy++;
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
      add(saveDrawing, gbc);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      (new testtable()).setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the code that you have now? Perhaps we could help you build off of it.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't do that coz its part of my thesis but here is the closes example which i get form internet. Its not exactly the same but close.

Comment: Still, you don't provide samples here, so best thing we can do is guess. So my guess is that you are messing with the Graphics2D methods? Then you can simply use the drawString method, no?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 0):

A little bit unclear, but i suppose you have overridden `paint` or `paintComponent` on some existing UI class and used `Graphics.drawLine` method to draw table grid.

If that's right, then you could make similar nested loop and call `Graphics.drawString` inside to render strings. Consider that strings are anchored by baseline, not by left-top corner.

UPD. Posted before your edits, so first part of answer is looking strange now.